# As per vs in accordance with

Tags: phrases, expressions, legalese

I am not a legal expert and English is not my first language. I have to make some changes in a draft of a legal document. I am not sure which sentence is correct. The situation is like

"Mr. ABC visiting DEF institute for three months, but during this
 period of time his living cost and salary should come from main
 employer XYZ, and DEF is not responsible."

> During this visit, Mr. ABC remains employed by XYZ, and he shall be paid full salary in accordance with the job contract with employer XYZ.

Vs

> During this visit, Mr. ABC remains employed by XYZ, and he shall be paid full salary as per the job contract with employer XYZ.

Comment: The English meaning or words does not always directly match the legal meaning of words. If you need the legal meaning it might be better to ask on [Law SE](https://law.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

"..."as per" is a horrible construction. It originated where "according to" was too long, and reports have been known to include 'numbers as per margin', instead of 'as set out in the margin.' It's not incomprehensible, but will never be regarded as "professional" - a reference after TimLymington's answer.